# How To Delete A Folder In Jar File?

Tags: java, jar, io, zip

I'm doing homework about manipulating JAR files. I can delete the files in a JAR file, but folders are still in it.

How do I delete them?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of current code.  BTW - AFAIU - Zip files (and Jars) do not contain 'folders'.

Comment: Err, delete the folders too?

Answer (score 3):

- To delete a folder in a jar file (make sure there is a trailing slash on the unwanted folder):

```
zip -d file.jar unwanted_folder/
```

- To delete a folder and all files inside:

```
zip -d file.jar unwanted_folder/\*
```

[Info sources](https://fabianlee.org/2018/10/30/linux-using-zip-unzip-to-add-update-and-remove-files-from-a-java-jar-war/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code to do this, but the basic idea is simple and should translate into almost any language the same way. The jar file layout is just a series of blocks that represent files (a header followed by the compressed data), finished off with a central directory that just contains all the metadata. Here's the process:

Scan forward in the file until you find the first file you want to delete.
Scan forward in the file until you find the first file you don't want to delete or you hit the central directory.
Scan forward in the file until you find the first file you want to delete or you hit the central directory.
Copy all the data you found in step 3 back onto the data you skipped in step 2 until you find another file you want to delete or you hit the central directory.
Go to step 2 unless you've hit the central directory.
Copy the central directory to where ever you left off copying, leaving out the entries for the deleted files and changing the offsets to reflect how much you moved each file.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29 for all the details on the ZIP file structures.

As bestsss suggests, you might want to perform the copying into another file, so as to prevent losing data in the event of a failure.